# How do i throw an exception if user input anything beside string?

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

I am stuck at where I want the user to enter a string only if the user enters a number is considered an invalid input.

Here is part of my code:

```
try {

    cout << "What is the model of your car? ";
    cin >> model;

    //Error checking 
    // if user enter anything beside string excute this block
    if (model ) {
        throw runtime_error("INVALID INPUT");
    }

    cout << "what year is your " << model << "? ";
    cin >> year;

    if (cin.fail()) {
        throw runtime_error("Not a number");
    }
    if (year < 0) {
        throw runtime_error("Year can't be negative");

    }
```

Comment: How do you expect to recognize any particular user input as *not* being a string?  What does that even mean?

Comment: Is "4-cylinder Civic" a number? Is "Toyota RAV4" a number? "99 Luftballoons"?

Comment: Unless `model` is declared something other than a string, the it will be a string. But it should of course be declared a string. What you probably really want is to write a function that verifies whether a string is a valid model. And in that case you don't throw an exception but rather display an error to the user and request a new input.

Comment: My car's model is "3".  Really.

Comment: A word on vocabulary: The _make_ is the name of the manufacturer, like “Audi”. The _model_ is the magic word/number/whatever that the manufacturer calls the car, like “Q3”.

Comment: That makes sense now. THank you for all of your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Well, model will always be a string, even if you put numbers in it. Because "1" is a string, and 65 is 'A', etc. But I think you mean how do you check if a string doesn't contain numbers.

```
bool contains_num(const std::string & str)
{
   bool ret = false;
   for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
      if(isdigit(str[i]))
         ret = true;
   return ret;
}
```

This function will catch edge cases like an empty string, too.

Comment: This kind of loop should be written with an early return: `if (isdigit(str[i])) return true;`. That way it doesn't do a bunch of unneeded tests.